# Import SQL records from file into sql DB and changing type

Tags: sql, sql-server, biginteger, sqlbulkcopy

I created a .txt file using BULK that contains all the records of a sql DB. Now I need to import these records into a new DB. The problem is that I need to change the type of some fields from DOUBLE to BIGINT or the records won't be added to the new DB.

Please, wich functions and how do I have to use them? 
Thanks

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Importing into SQL Server, you can right-click on the database and select Tasks > Import Data. This will open up the Import/Export Wizard which is a slimmed down version of the same functionality in SSIS.

Once the Wizard is open, you can navigate the through the prompts and eventually get to a screen, Select Source Data, where you can click on the Edit Mappings button and modify the data types of the data being imported.